# FireBase, Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

cuando intento compilar para subir una nueva versión de mi app al Appstore, me aparece este problema:

> ```
> "   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)   "
> ```

He probado de todo, el único cambio que hice en mi app fue vincularla a AdMob...estoy trabajando con Xcode 8.2 y Swift...

Alguien tiene idea de qué puede ser? alguien a quien le haya pasado algo similar. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Selecciona tu target, ve a `Build Settings` > `Other Linker Flags` y añade `$(inherited)`

Haz un clean `Cmd+Ctrl+K` para asegurarte y vuelve a probar.